# Correct way to format Delegate event within AddListener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I'm just learning how to implement delegates in my code and I having a bit of trouble with the logic. I want to call on event on a button click using an AddListener method but I'm getting the error

> The event EventManager.OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked can only appear on the left
>   hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'EventManager')

in the line of code `newDriftBtn.onClick.AddListener(EventManager.OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked(driftNumSteps, driftName));`

What is the correct way to format this line? Thank you!

GameManager.cs

```
public void AddListeners()
{
    newDriftBtn.onClick.AddListener(EventManager.OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked(driftNumSteps, driftName));
}
```

EventManager.cs

```
public class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void GenerateNewDriftSetHandler(int steps, string title);
    public static event GenerateNewDriftSetHandler OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked;
}
```

GenerateNewDrift.cs

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    EventManager.OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked += InitDrift;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    EventManager.OnGenerateNewDriftSetClicked -= InitDrift;
}

public void InitDrift(int driftNumSteps, string driftName)
{
    string driftID = GenerateDriftID();

    CreateTable(driftID);
    PopulateTable(driftID, driftName, driftNumSteps);
}
```